# Create a list by looping over numbers in different dict

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to create a list by looping over days and months in year 2020 and if month + day + year = 7 then I need to add that to the list. However if the month is 11 then the program should do 1 + 1 = 2 (and not 11) so instead of using lists I have done a dict with values. But I'm not if I'm missing something.

Here is my code so far:

```py
day = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7, 8:8, 9:9, 10:1, 11:2, 12:3, 13:4, 14:5, 15:6, 16:7, 17:8, 18:9, 19:10, 20:2, 21:3, 22:4, 23:5, 24:6, 25:7, 26:8, 27:9, 28:10, 29:11, 30:3, 31:4}
month = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7, 8:8, 9:9, 10:1, 11:2, 12:3,}
year = {20:2}
dagar_007 = []

def ordning(m,d,y):    
    for y in year.values():
        for m in month.values():
            if m == 2:
                for d in day.values():
                    if y + m + d == 7:
                        if d == 30:
                            break
                        dagar_007.append(ordning)
            elif m == 4 or 6 or 8 or 11:
                for d in day.values():
                    if y + m + d == 7:
                        if d == 31:
                            break
                        dagar_007.append(ordning)
            else:                                               
                for d in day.values():
                    if y + m + d == 7:
                        dagar_007.append(ordning)
                        if d == 32:
                            break
print(dagar_007)

# How it kind of looks like

print("List of days with sum 7:")
# 1/4/20 007

print(dagar_007, "007")

print(datetime.datetime.strftime(x,"%m/%d/%y"))

print("Sannolikheten: ", len(dagar_007) / 366 * 100, "%")
print("in other words:", len(dagar_007), "chances on 366")
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

try this code for building your list

```
def one_digit_nunmber(number):
return sum([int(i) for i in list(number)])

month = [str(i) for i in range(1, 13)]
year = [str(i) for i in range(20, 21)]
result = []
for y in year:
    for m in month:
        if m in ["2"]:
            day = [str(i) for i in range(1, 30)]
        elif m in ["4", "6", "8", "11"]:
            day = [str(i) for i in range(1, 31)]
        else:
            day = [str(i) for i in range(1, 32)]
        result += [(d, m, y) for d in day if one_digit_nunmber(y + m + d) == 7]

print(result)
```